# Getting the SUM of Points(column in table) Group By CustomerID with a condition on Date(duration)

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum, having

I have a table of transactions, for each Customer has several transactions with points for each transaction.

I need to run a mysql query to find the sum of points for each customer in a certain duration of time.

Each  transaction has a CustomerID , Points, TranactionDate

The problem is that I need to find the SUM(Points) GroupBY CustomerID for only transactions that Date range between two dates.

like this:

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT `Points` FROM `transaction` 
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '30/09/2012' AND '4/10/2012') 
    GROUP BY `CustomerID`
```

please I need the equivalent query for  the above one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are those real dates? Saved as DATE in MySQL? It won't work if they are VARCHAR fields.

Comment: no not real dates , h=just to give example, the dates are datetime 2012-04-14

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(Points) as customerPoints FROM transaction 
    WHERE Date BETWEEN '30/09/2012' AND '4/10/2012' 
    GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `CustomerID`, SUM(`Points`) AS `Points`
FROM `transaction`
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '30/09/2012' AND '4/10/2012'
GROUP BY `CustomerID`
```